# Cascading Dropdown Problem

Tags: sharepoint-rest-api, error, cascading-dropdown

Why am I getting this error:

> "Error retrieving information from list: Functional Areas{"error":"-1,Microsoft.SharePoint.SPException","message":{"lang":"en-US","value":"The field or property 'Hospital' does not exist."}}}

But the field 'Hospital' is definitely in the childlist.

Please advise.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess internal name of your field is different than 'Hospital'.

Use below link to check the internal name of your field:

[How to check Column Internal Name for a SharePoint List](https://ganeshsanapblogs.wordpress.com/2023/04/17/how-to-find-the-internal-name-of-sharepoint-columns/).

Also add the code you are using that might be helpful to answer your question.

Comment: you are a star ganesh! thank you very much.

Comment: Welcome. Glad it helped you.